# Sampling from depth texture always results 0

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shadow-mapping

I am attempting to implement shadow mapping using opengl, using a directional light.

I have confirmed that the depth texture is correctly rendered, like so:
[image: depth texture]

And to perform a visual inspection, I also output the world space coordinates, transformed to light perspective:

[image: shadow coords]

Which again, seems to be ok.

However, when I sample the depth texture, using:

```
vec3 coord = vec3(shadowCoords.xy,shadowCoords.z/shadowCoords.w);
float depth = texture( shadowMap, coord);
```

I find that the comparison always fails. If I change `uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap;` to `uniform sampler2D shadowMap;`, and sample the texture directly using `texture( shadowMap, coord.xy).r`, I find that the sampled value is always zero, by outputting this result to the screen.

I created the depth texture like so:

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_DepthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_DepthTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_DepthTexture, 0);
```

and my shader code is as follows(vertex):

```
#version 430
// Some drivers require the following
precision highp float;
layout (location = 0)in vec3 MSVertex;
layout (location = 4)in vec2 MSTexCoord;

out xferBlock
{
    vec3 VSVertex;
    vec2 VSTexCoord;
} outdata;

void main()
{
    outdata.VSVertex = MSVertex;
    outdata.VSTexCoord = MSTexCoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(MSVertex,1.0);
}
```

and fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core
// Some drivers require the following
precision highp float;

layout (location = 0) uniform sampler2D positionMap;
layout (location = 1) uniform sampler2D normalMap;
layout (location = 2) uniform sampler2D colourMap;
layout (location = 3) uniform sampler2D specularMap;
layout (location = 4) uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap;

struct DirLightData
{
    vec4 colour;
    float intensity;
    vec4 direction;
};
uniform mat4 ShadowTransform;
uniform DirLightData dirLight;
out vec4 colour;
uniform vec3 WSCamPos;
in xferBlock
{
    vec3 VSVertex;
    vec2 VSTexCoord;
} indata;

vec3 computeLight(vec3 Ldirection, vec3 Vdirection, vec3 Lcolour, vec3 normal, float Lintensity, float specular)
{
    vec3 diffCol = Lcolour * max(0.0,dot(normalize(normal),-Ldirection));
    vec3 reflectVec = normalize(reflect(Ldirection,normal));
    float specFactor = max(dot(reflectVec,Vdirection),0);
    float specPow = pow(specFactor,specular*255.0);
    vec3 specCol = Lcolour * specPow;
    return (diffCol+specCol)*Lintensity;;
}
float computeOcclusion(vec4 shadowCoords)
{
    float vis = 1.0;
    vec3 coord = vec3(shadowCoords.xyz/shadowCoords.w);
    float depth = texture( shadowMap, vec3(coord.xy,coord.z+0.05));
    if (  depth < coord.z);
    {
        vis = 0.5;
    }
    return vis;
}
void main()
{
    vec4 pcolour = texture(positionMap, indata.VSTexCoord).rgba;
    vec4 ncolour = texture(normalMap, indata.VSTexCoord).rgba;
    vec4 dcolour = texture(colourMap, indata.VSTexCoord).rgba;
    vec4 scolour = texture(specularMap, indata.VSTexCoord).rgba;

    vec4 shadowCoord = ShadowTransform * pcolour;
    float visibility = computeOcclusion( shadowCoord );
    //float depth = texture(shadowMap, shadowCoord.xy).z;
    vec3 vToEye = WSCamPos - pcolour.xyz;
    vToEye = normalize(vToEye);
    vec3 outColour = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);

    outColour = computeLight(dirLight.direction.xyz,vToEye,dirLight.colour.rgb,ncolour.rgb,dirLight.intensity,scolour.r);
    colour = vec4(visibility*(dcolour.rgb*outColour),1.0);

}
```

Can anyone spot where this is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems like this are hard to spot so here are a few things that you need to take a look at:

1. You are using a `samplerShadow` which is special in it's own way, you need to set [`COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_fragment_program_shadow.txt) and with that you don't need that `if` statement. Alternatively you can use `sampler2D`, but you need to do an `if` statement in the shader, something similar to what you did, but the coord has to be `vec2` not `vec3`
2. consider using `textureProj` with `vec4` texture coord. because it's much easier to transform world position in light space using a matrix multiplication. It's the same matrix that you use for rendering the shadow map in the first place. In your case it's this value `vec4 shadowCoord = ShadowTransform * pcolour;`; use `shadowCoord` directly with `textureProj`.

Comment: About 2: If you use a `sampler2D` instead of `sampler2DShadow`, you wouldn't be using PCF anymore.

Comment: Two things worked: removing the if statement and directly using the sampled depth, and calling glCullFace(GL_FRONT) before rendering the depth map.

It appears that I had a very fine grain shadow acne problem, which wasn't easy to see.

Comment: Whilst the answer wasn't *exactly* right, it did give me food for thought and point me in the right direction, so thanks.

Comment: @Ian Young can you tell us the solution so we can post this for future reference ?

Comment: @Raxvan Yes, I'll do so in an answer of my own.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that my sampling was returning the correct value.

The real issue was a very fine grained shadow acne caused by culling the back faces of the geometry when rendering the depth map, and handling the return value from sampling the depth texture incorrectly.

I changed the sampling function to:

```
float computeOcclusion(vec4 shadowCoords)
{
    vec3 coord = vec3(shadowCoords.xyz/shadowCoords.w);
    float depth = texture( shadowMap, vec3(coord.xy,coord.z+0.001));
    return depth;
}
```

And changed my depth rendering gl client code to include:

```
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
```

Prior to rendering the geometry to the shadowMap.

Once this was done, I got the following result:
[image: final render]

There are still some peter panning issues, but that's something I can deal with separately.